# Ignore column in WHERE

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

Can I ignore some columns in WHERE condition?

```
SELECT name FROM people
WHERE name LIKE 'Honza' AND surname LIKE 'Novak'
```

*(I recieve the WHERE condition as parametr unable to edit it)*

Comment: you'll like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338739/inverse-of-sql-like-value

Comment: Nice, but I am not able to edit the where condition.

Comment: If you can't change the parameter passed to you, what *can* you change? What is passed in that parameter? `name LIKE 'Honza' AND surname LIKE 'Novak'`or `WHERE name LIKE 'Honza' AND surname LIKE 'Novak'` or ...

Comment: The query looks like this `SELECT name FROM people {WHERE}`. Into the {WHERE} placeholder system puts the WHERE condition. But the system generate condition with one more column that I do not know.

Comment: In the statement is `((name LIKE 'Honza') AND (surname LIKE 'Novak'))`

Comment: Can you change the query to `SELECT name FROM people {WHERE} OR (name LIKE 'Honza')`? This would eliminate the surname condition.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because there are more columns in condition. Exactly it looks like this `((date >= '2011-08-01'::timestamp) AND (date <= '2011-09-30') AND (ico = '72186000'))`. But my rows do not know the `ico`. I can add the `ico` to `SELECT name, NULL AS ico FROM...` but I cannot add (OR ico IS NULL) to filter, because it would ignore the date filtering also.

Comment: @karel - Didn't you just answer your own question? What's wrong with adding the `ico` column to your select clause? Perhaps even more importantly, *why* is the condition added if the `ico` column doesn't exist?

Comment: The whole thing is little more complicate. I have two tables with different structures. I mine data from these tables, unify them and join with `UNION`. The problem is that one of these tables does not have the `ico`. Plus from first table I need data filtered by `ico`, from second table I need ALL rows (no matter of `ico` because it's not known there).

Comment: @Karel - I doubt you will find a foolproof solution to this. It would require you to parse the where condition yourself but for the given statement, adding `SELECT name, '72186000' AS ico FROM...` would work.

Comment: Too bad. I will probably use some `WITH` and first select the first table (with `ico`) and then somehow `JOIN` results from the second table (there are a lot of `SUM, MAX etc.` so it woun't be so easy as it sounds). Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Karel - I would suggest to delete this question and repost with all the information you've now provided through comments. Others might very well come up with a solution. It would help if we know what *the system* is. Perhaps there *is* a way to alter the `{WHERE}`clause you and I don't know about.

Comment: What rows, exactly, do you want to ignore?  You can always just pass the query in as a subquery:  `select name from (select name from people where name like 'Honza' and surname like 'Novak') where <blahblahblah>`

Comment: @Lieven - It's company framework and I'm sure that I can't alter {WHERE} clause.

Comment: Looks I got it. I need 6 `WITH` statements and some JOINs. Not nice but it works :P So I guess the answer to original question is NO. @Lieven if you post this as an answer, I'm going to mark it. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Karel - I would suggest instead to post your final solution and mark that as accepted. I'm curious to know how the final solution looks like starting from the querie(s) we ended up with.

Comment: @Lieven Ok, but as a StackOverflow novice, I need to wait 4 more hours to answer my own question ;)

Comment: @karel - AFAIK, that "restriction" applies to all of us, no matter what reputation you have.

Comment: -1 for a unclear question. It takes endless comments (most of it should be edited into the question instead!) to somewhat clarify the problem. Please show some more effort in phrasing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer here is no, you cannot.  You got the where condition and if you can't edit it, it will be processed as is.  If you can add to the end you could add an AND and an OR to override, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do some string replacement on the WHERE? E.g.

```
replace($WHERE, "surname like 'Novak'", "surname like '%'")
```

If not, you can maybe hack something with a `ON SELECT INSTEAD...` rule:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrule.html